# How do we write script to kill PID ( If else loop )?

Tags: linux, shell-script, process, kill

I have a file which will contain multiple PIDs as show below.

```
#cat /scripts/pid.txt
12345
23456
34567
45678
```

I have to write  a script which will read the PID's from above file one by one and kill them. If script stuck if any PID is not getting killed script should exit and go for next PID killing.

Here is my script:

```
filename_java=/scripts/pid.txt
cat ${filename_java} | while read line
do

echo "The $line PID is still running" >> 
$TC_LOGS/killing_pid_aftershutdown_$DATE.txt
echo "killing the PID $line " >> 
$TC_LOGS/killing_pid_aftershutdown_java_$DATE.txt
kill -15 $line && sleep 5
mail -s "Admin console is shutdown gracefully" -r $LOGNAME@$HOSTNAME <email 
id> < /dev/null

done
```

**Before reading the pids one by one we should check if file is having that PIDs or not if yes kill them and if not exit.**

Thanks
Santosh G.

Comment: which if else, where is it?

Comment: I mean i have done with while loop but i want this to be done with the help of if else loop.

Comment: It is not clear why you want a if else and for what.

Comment: Is it clear now.

Comment: You wrote, "_script should exit and go for next PID killing_". If the script exits then it's no longer running and so cannot kill any other PID. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: A kill does not get stuck, and the original question was so much better with the script(s). Just the premise is wrong. I would advise also picking better titles, and avoiding requests in the title. That is what the question body is for. btw it is not the PID being killed per se.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the bold text, "_Before reading the pids one by one we should check if file is having that PIDs or not if yes kill them and if not exit._". It's clearly important to you, so please can you either clarify this or provide examples of what you mean. Do you simply mean that there should be a check that the file exists before trying to use it?

Comment: @Roaima Yes exactly I just want make sure if file exists & do the action only if file has the pid or some content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a trivial level, I'm not entirely sure why this wouldn't suffice.

```
[[ -s "/scripts/pid_$DATE.txt" ]] && kill $(cat "/scripts/pid_$DATE.txt")
```

Or do you need only the first one to be killed, and the others left alone?

```
if [[ -s "/scripts/pid_$DATE.txt" ]] 
then
    while IFS= read -r pid
    do
        kill "$pid" && break
    done <"$scripts/pid_$DATE.txt"
fi
```

In both cases it is assumed that the script has sufficient privileges to signal the target processes, and that the `"$scripts/pid_$DATE.txt"` file either does not exist, or is trusted and up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Not that clear but "kill" does not get stuck, so,

```
while read pid; do kill "$pid"; done < "/scripts/pid_$DATE.txt"
```

or add -9 to kill to violently kill your process

Answer (score 1):

The other answers show what you should do, but don't really answer your question. So, here you go.

To check a pid exists, run `ps p $pid` and check the return code.

So you can do:

```
if ps p $pid; then
    kill $pid
fi
```

or

```
ps p $pid && kill $pid
```

---

To read through a file:

```
while IFS= read -r pid
do
    ps p $pid && kill "$pid"
done < "/scripts/pid_$DATE.txt"
```

or use `xargs` instead of the loop:

```
xargs -a "/scripts/pid_$DATE.txt" -I{} sh -c '
    ps p $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 && kill $1
' xargs-sh {}
```

---

> As the others pointed out, all this is not necessary as your premise that `kill` could get stuck is wrong.